# Google Play Leaderboard not showing up after posting score to leaderboard in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, leaderboard

I have enabled google play games plugin in my Unity Project. The Unity version is 5.3.4f1. The google play games plugin version is 0.9.32. I have successfully logged in to the google play games service in my project. After submitting the score,and when I try to view the leaderboard, its showing an error like this in the log:

```
04-29 09:58:53.537: I/Unity(6910):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 04/29/16 9:58:53 +05:30 DEBUG: Entering internal callback for AndroidPlatformConfiguration#InternalIntentHandler

04-29 09:58:53.537: I/Unity(6910): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

04-29 09:58:53.575: I/Unity(6910):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 04/29/16 9:58:53 +05:30 DEBUG: Application is pausing, which disconnects the RTMP  client.  Leaving room.

04-29 09:58:53.575: I/Unity(6910): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

04-29 09:58:55.940: D/GamesUnitySDK(6910): Forwarding OnActivityResult

04-29 09:58:55.963: D/GamesUnitySDK(6910): Forwarding OnActivityResult Finished

04-29 09:58:55.999: I/Unity(6910):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 04/29/16 9:58:55 +05:30 DEBUG: Showing UI Internal callback: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED

04-29 09:58:55.999: I/Unity(6910): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

04-29 09:58:56.077: I/Unity(6910):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 04/29/16 9:58:56 +05:30 DEBUG: Invoking user callback on game thread

04-29 09:58:56.077: I/Unity(6910): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

04-29 09:58:56.085: I/Unity(6910):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 04/29/16 9:58:56 +05:30 DEBUG: Received UI callback: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED

04-29 09:58:56.085: I/Unity(6910): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

04-29 09:59:54.185: I/Unity(6910):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 04/29/16 9:59:54 +05:30 DEBUG: Application is pausing, which disconnects the RTMP  client.  Leaving room.

04-29 09:59:54.185: I/Unity(6910): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)
```

I'm getting an error like this

> DEBUG: Received UI callback: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED

I have successfully login also, but still its showing as Error not authorized. Here is my code.

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;

public class GooglePlayGameService : MonoBehaviour {
void Start()
{
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
   .RequireGooglePlus()
   .Build();

    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool Success)=>{
        if(Success)
        {
            mStatusText = "Welcome " + Social.localUser.userName;
            Debug.Log("Success Google Play Games");
        }
        else
        {
            mStatusText = "Authentication failed.";
            //ShowNextScene ();
            Debug.Log("failed Google Play Games");
        }

    });
}
}

public void ShowScoreBoard()
{

   Debug.Log("User Authenticated: " + Social.localUser.authenticated); 
   if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
        ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI("leaderboard id here");
}
```

When I check whether the user is authenticated or not, it is returning true, when I debug it. But the leaderboard is not showing up. can some one please help me in solving this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

if **EnableSavedGames()** is used in the Builder(), then you'll need to **toggle on** **SavedGames** support in the **Developer Console** and also enable **Drive API** in the "**API Console Project**". The place to reach all of this would be the **"Game Details"** page in the **Developer Console**.

make sure you dont have multiple `debug.keystore` on your computer
and your SHA1 on the Developer Console and build should be the same

Comment: Enable Saved Games is turned off in developer console. There is nothing to enable in the API Console Project in developer console. I cant find the drive API. Can you please help me.

Comment: turn it on not off

Comment: I have turned on, but still its not loading leaderboard.

Comment: check if your SHA1 on the Developer Console is different from the  build

Comment: I have added the release keystore in the unity project, as the project is going to release soon. Create a SHA1 key using the release keystore and given the sha1 in the google play developer console too.

Comment: I dont have multiple debug.keystore in my computer

Comment: @MiladQasemi I have one keystore I created and only one. However, I have 2 key aliases at the player settings: the *Unsigned (debug)* and the custom key created. Was this issue count or can still show leaderboard?