# Unity android build exception

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am using multiple sdks in unity like Facebook, Play Services and Unity Ads and i am getting the following exception on attempting an android build.

CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/india/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "D:\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/AnimatorRes;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/AnyRes;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/ArrayRes;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/AttrRes;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/BinderThread;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/BoolRes;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/CallSuper;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/CheckResult;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

Can anyone make any meaning out of this.

Comment: This happens when using FaceBook and GooglePlayServices at the-same time. Can't believe this has not been fixed since then. This is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36910494/3785314), so check if that solution is still working.

Comment: Yes @Programmer ! duplicate libraries are the ultimate reason here.

Comment: I followed the solution (Go to Assets->FacebookSDK->Plugins->Android->libs then delete android-support-v4.jar), but its still giving the exception.

Comment: The solution likely changed after updates. You need to delete more of the duplicated files. Read the other 2 answers under the question.