# Unity Facebook SDK v 7.7 and Google Play Services

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, facebook-unity-sdk

B.S: I am specifically talking about facebook-unity-sdk-7.7.0 not v 7.3.0
I am using `facebook-unity-sdk-7.7.0` and `GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.32` in my project. It does not let me build for android and fails with error `Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.`. In Facebook SDK 7.3.0 it works by deleting android support v4, but in 7.7 the same thing does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to build for android with facebook sdk and google play together in Unity 5.3.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491498/unable-to-build-for-android-with-facebook-sdk-and-google-play-together-in-unity)

Comment: it is a different version

Comment: I know it is. Try that. If it doesn't work then upload a simple project somewhere and provide a link to it here. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and this was the way I solved it:
Delete the following files from the folder:
\ Assets \ FacebookSDK \ Plugins \ Android \ libs:

- support-annotations-23.4.0.jar
- support-annotations-23.4.0.meta
- support-v4-23.4.0.aar
- support-v4-23.4.0.meta